# Issue with "new" routing when upgrading from rails 3.2.0 to 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, new-operator, edit

I have some issues with routing when upgrading rails from 3.2.0 to 3.2.2.

When generating a new route with the routes helper the helper works and generates a link that looks like:

```
/things/new
```

However when you visit the link it throws a routing error...

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"app/things", :id=>#<Thing id: nil, title: n....
```

It mistakes it for an edit url actions not a new one.

There is nothing in the routes but....

```
  scope :module => :app, :as => :app, :constraints => { :subdomain => /app/ } do
     resources :things
  end
```

Has anyone experienced this or know what's happening?

Thanks.

Extra details...

Rake routes:

```
    app_things GET    /things(.:format)                                    app/things#index {:subdomain=>/app/}
               POST   /things(.:format)                                    app/things#create {:subdomain=>/app/}
 new_app_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)                                app/things#new {:subdomain=>/app/}
edit_app_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format)                           app/things#edit {:subdomain=>/app/}
     app_thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)                                app/things#show {:subdomain=>/app/}
               PUT    /things/:id(.:format)                                app/things#update {:subdomain=>/app/}
               DELETE /things/:id(.:format)                                app/things#destroy {:subdomain=>/app/}
```

Curl:

```
curl -IL http://app.testapp.com/things/new
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

From the log (stack trace?):

```
    Started GET "/things/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-24 19:27:02 +0100
Processing by App::ThingsController#new as HTML
  Rendered app/things/_new_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered app/things/new.html.erb within layouts/app (2.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_app_includes.html.erb (11.0ms)
  Rendered app/nav/_things_new.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered app/nav/_menu_wrapper.html.erb (2.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"app/things", :id=>#<Thing id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, account_id: nil>}):
  app/views/app/nav/_step_1_title.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_app_nav__step___title_html_erb__3644446743043796555_70280275307960'
  app/views/app/nav/_things_new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_app_nav__things_new_html_erb__4471631226426153422_70280275315660'
  app/views/app/nav/_menu_wrapper.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_app_nav__menu_wrapper_html_erb___3003322303253991863_70280275346820'
  app/views/layouts/app.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_layouts_app_html_erb__4514085623626236526_70280285513740'


  Rendered /Users/blerg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)
```

Comment: Can you post a `rake routes` output?

Comment: Would like to see a stacktrace also.

Comment: Added some extra details above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that it is not the `/things/new` route itself that is causing the problem. There is something being rendered (one of your _nav menus, for example) that includes a call to `edit_app_thing_path` with a nil or otherwise missing object parameter.

Comment: Agreed - anything suspicious in "_step_1_title.html.erb" Smickie?

Comment: Yeah this was it, it was strange because it was never throwing an error before the upgrade. And the looked like one that wasn't being thrown in the view too. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Check your development.log file to see the full stack trace when you visit "/things/new". Post it here if you can't see whats wrong from the log.

On first glance, there seem to be problem in the `edit_thing_path(@thing)` call: you are passing new record to it - I see `#<Thing id: nil...` in that error message.

Comment: Definitely an issue, but it shouldn't even be going to the edit path to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

### Works fine over here.

I don't know what to tell you Smickie, I re-created your situation and it worked fine for me. Here are some details:

*Rails Version*

```
$ bundle exec rails -v
Rails 3.2.2
```

*Routes.rb*

```
scope :module => :app, :as => :app, :constraints => { :subdomain => /app/ } do
  resources :things
end
```

*Rake Routes*

```
$ bundle exec rake routes
    app_things GET    /things(.:format)          app/things#index {:subdomain=>/app/}
               POST   /things(.:format)          app/things#create {:subdomain=>/app/}
 new_app_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)      app/things#new {:subdomain=>/app/}
edit_app_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format) app/things#edit {:subdomain=>/app/}
     app_thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)      app/things#show {:subdomain=>/app/}
               PUT    /things/:id(.:format)      app/things#update {:subdomain=>/app/}
               DELETE /things/:id(.:format)      app/things#destroy {:subdomain=>/app/}
```

*Getting `things/new`*

```
$ curl -IL http://app.test.dev:3001/things/new
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

#### If you post the same details from your machine, we'll see what's fishy.

Comment: Cheers. Added some more details like you asked.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
scope "/app" do
  resources :things
end
```